# "Season's greetings" or "Seasoned greetings"

Tags: idioms, greetings, christmas, eggcorn, catachresis

Today I heard the phrase "Seasoned greetings." Is this just some clever word play on the traditional "Season's greetings,"  meant to mean greetings spiced up with seasoning, or is it a legitimate idiom?

Comment: What is the general tenor of the usage on Google?

Comment: I've never heard "seasoned greetings" as a legitimate idiom.